# Find $\ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ if $\ z=f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Find$\ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ if$\ z=f(x,y)$ is differentiable and satisfies the following equation:

$\ xe^{yz} - 2ye^{xz} + 3ze^{xy} = 1$

I don't get it, do I have to substitute$\ z$ in the equation and just compute the partial derivatives or is there something more?

Comment: Do you know about implicit differentiation?

Comment: I saw some examples, but I still don't get. I thought of differentiating both sides of the equation, but don't wich variable I should use to differentiate

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $x$ (treat $y$ as constant) first. Then start over and differentiate with respect to $y$ (treat $x$ as constant).

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out and see if I get it right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(x,y,z)=xe^{yz}-2ye^{xz}+3ze^{xy}-1=0$;$z_x\overset{def}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$; $z_y\overset{def}=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(xe^{yz}-2ye^{xz}+3ze^{xy}-1)=$$

$$=e^{yz}(1+xyz_x)-2ye^{xz}(z+xz_x)+3e^{xy}(z_x+zy)=0$$

$$z_x(xye^{yz}-2yxe^{xz}+3e^{xy})+e^{yz}-2yze^{xz}+3zye^{xy}=0$$

$$z_x=\frac{-e^{yz}+2yze^{xz}-3zye^{xy}}{xye^{yz}-2yxe^{xz}+3e^{xy}}$$

And the same for $z_y$...

Use the magnifying glass to see $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}xe^{yz}$. It's a product of $x$, that depends on $x$ directly, with derivative $1$, and $e^{yz}$ that depends on $x$ trough $z$, with derivative $yz_xe^{yz}$, so $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}xe^{yz}=e^{yz}+xyz_xe^{yz}$